# @Valid, @NotEmpty not working in my spring application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, gson

I created a class which had `@Valid` and `@NotEmpty` annotation. I am not using the class to pass request body but I am creating it's object later in my application and then the annotations are not working.
Request Body:

```
String jsonData;
```

I am converting this jsonData to Json Object using gson library

JSON OBJECT CLASS
JsonObject.class

```
@NotEmpty
@Valid
List<JsonObject> list;
public static class innerClass {
  @NotEmpty
  private String name;
  @NotEmpty
  private int age;
}
```

Implementation of gson:

```
JsonObject json = gson.fromJson(requestBody.getJsonData(), JsonObject.class); //this should give error if I pass age or name as empty but it's not showing error
```

If  I pass  request body as  follow , it should throw an error but its not.

```
{"jsonData":"{}"}
```

Comment: Why do you think `fromJson` should handle validation and throw a validation error? Deserialize it and then validate it. Spring MVC does exactly the same. That's it.

Comment: Isn't ```fromJson()``` doing deserialisation only?

Comment: This is what I was talking about. Making fromJson doing validation, i.e. JSR-303, is a bad idea.

Answer (score 1):

Please add dependency `spring-boot-starter-validation`

```
 <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
   <version>2.4.0</version>
</dependency>
```